# Join two excel table

Tags: sql, excel

I have two excel table structure and order

structure contain

```
Product | Component | Order_Quantity
A       | C1        | 1 
A       | C2        | 3 
A       | C3        | 3 
B       | C1        | 1 
B       | C4        | 2 
C       | C1        | 1 
D       | C2        | 3 
C       | C3        | 3
```

order contain

```
Order_n | Product | Quantity
1       | A       | 10
2       | B       | 10
3       | A       | 10
4       | C       | 10
6       | B       | 10
```

How can i join the two table in excel 2013 (without power pivot or another add-in) to see result like this :

```
Order_n | Product | Order_Qty | component | Quantity | Total_QTY
1       | A       | 10        | C1        | 1        | 10
1       | A       | 10        | C2        | 3        | 30
1       | A       | 10        | C3        | 3        | 30
2       | B       | 10        | C1        | 1        | 10
2       | B       | 10        | C4        | 2        | 20
3       | A       | 10        | C1        | 1        | 10
3       | A       | 10        | C2        | 3        | 30
3       | A       | 10        | C3        | 3        | 30
4       | C       | 10        | C1        | 1        | 10
4       | C       | 10        | C3        | 3        | 30
6       | B       | 10        | C1        | 1        | 10
6       | B       | 10        | C4        | 2        | 20
```

Comment: In Excel select Data->FromOtherSources->FromMicrosoftQuery. Select Excel Files. Locate your Excel file with these two sheets and import data. there will be a wizard that will allow you to join these sheets the way you want it

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use VBA.
This should work... Couldn't test the whole thing, so let me know if it works.

```
Sub JoinTables()

    Dim cn
    Dim rs
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strTbl1 As String
    Dim strTbl2 As String
    Dim JoinField As String
    Dim Table1Name As String
    Dim Table2Name As String
    Dim Table3Address As String
    Dim Table1Worksheet As String
    Dim Table2Worksheet As String
    Dim Table3Worksheet As String



    ' CHANGE THESE!
    Table1Name = "structure": Table1Worksheet = "Sheet1"  ' Name of table and name of the worksheet it is on
    Table2Name = "order": Table2Worksheet = "Sheet1"
    Table3Address = "A2": Table3Worksheet = "Sheet2"  ' The result
    JoinField = "Product"
    ' ==================================

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    strTbl1 = " [" & Table1Worksheet & "$" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Table1Worksheet).ListObjects(Table1Name).Range.AddressLocal, "$", "") & "] AS T1 "
    strTbl2 = " [" & Table2Worksheet & "$" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Table2Worksheet).ListObjects(Table2Name).Range.AddressLocal, "$", "") & "] AS T2 "
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTbl1 & " LEFT JOIN " & strTbl2 & " ON T1." & JoinField & "=T2." & JoinField

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Table3Worksheet).Range(Table3Address).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Why use VB when there is native functionality to do it?

Comment: i'm trying to avoid VBA and add-in and use a native fuctionality instead ; how can i do this in a native way ?

Comment: It bugs me that now for the third time in a row, OP's only remark "that is not quite what I wanted", not "thank you for the time you took for me" (you don;t write something like that in just 5 minutes). Be clearer about what you want and be more grateful, please. Well, I'm done with providing answers on this website. Ciao.

Comment: thanks Roemer, i'm so sorry and grateful for your effort but i search for a solution whitout the use of vba.